# What sounds better/more natural in this case: "for" or "because of"?

Tags: word-choice

> I abandoned everything for animal behavior.
>
> I abandoned everything because of animal behavior.

What's the best option? Or would the meaning differ? (I'm hesitant because, unlike, for instance, medicine or law, animal behavior is not a career or something you can "pursue", but rather a topic.)

Comment: I abandoned everything to focus on animal behavior.

Comment: They could mean different things and it's not clear what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your information doesn't seem quite true:

**career in animal behavior research** [if you mean research]

is out there:

> Origins and Evolution of Behavior Disorders: From Infancy ... - Page
>   62 Stella Chess - 1987
>
> Finally we approached our friend Dr. Herbert Birch, who at that time
>   was turning from a brilliant **career in animal behavior research** to
>   the study of neurobehavioral patterns in the young infant.

thus I'd opt for:

*I abandoned everything **for** a **career in animal behavior research***

or:

*I abandoned everything **in favor of**  a **career in animal behavior research***

BTW,

*I abandoned everything because of animal behavior.*

would be a poor choice, as it's ambiguous and it could mean that your dog chased you out of the house :-)

Also, watch your grammar:

What's sounds better --> **What** sounds better

Answer (score 2):

Neither if your sentences say anything about a **career** in the **field of** Animal Behavior (<--- capitalized)

What your sentences say are:

## 1 I abandoned civilization and decided to live like an animal.

## 2 Because of my animalistic behavior I had to give up everything I had.

Perhaps you were arrested for public indecency? And lost all you had paying fines and lawyers?

Answer (score 2):

> I abandoned everything for animal behavior.
>
> I abandoned everything because of animal behavior.

In addition to what others have said: The first of these is ambiguous. It could mean that you abandoned everything in your normal behavior in order to adopt animal-like behavior. *For* in that case suggests that your behavior moves toward, or becomes more like, that of an animal.